# How to put Ajax response in html select option using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am using ajax to get response and my respone is coming in below format

Array
(
    [2] => Electric Hammer
    [3] => Electric Planer
    [10] => housekeeping
    [11] => test category
)

how to put it's value and text for html select option using jquery.

Please Help me

Comment: html form is
<select id="UserSubcategory" name="datavalue">
<option value=""></option>
</select>

Comment: Hello zerkms i used this but i am doing something wrong.
Can you please give me proper code?

Comment: what exactly is wrong, are there any errors?

Comment: @vin: `select.append(newOption);` <--- this is proper code

Comment: I used this:
.each(response, function(key, value) {   
     $('#UserSubcategory')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",key)
         .text(value)); 
});
but it is not working.

Comment: @zerkms: it shows all value of response array in option
means like this
<select id="UserSubcategory" name="data[User][subcategory]">
<option value=""></option>
Array
(
    [2] =&gt; Electric Hammer
    [3] =&gt; Electric Planer
    [10] =&gt; housekeeping
    [11] =&gt; test category
)
</select>

Comment: @vin is that array an actual JavaScript object?

Comment: @dave no, of course it's not, it's a PHP array being passed as a string (for some reason). you should try to `json_encode` that string before you send it to the server.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: right. actully i fetched list value form database and send to it ajax response. now i want to these value in select options.

Comment: @vin then you need to take the variable that outputs that array, and use `json_encode($array)` so it sends it back as a parsable construct

Comment: do you have that array in json format in your ajax response?

Answer (score 0):

After you fetch your array from DB return this html in response

```
$html = "";
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $val) {
    $html .= "<option value="{$i}">{$val}</option>";
}
```

and then using jQuery you can put that in select tag

your html code will be like this

```
<select id="my-options"></select>
```

your jquery code will be as follows, response will be ajax response and options will contain the desired html

```
$('#my-options').html(response.options)
```